# Stop a scrollviewer from scrolling on key up/down

Tags: vb.net, xaml, silverlight-4.0, scroll

I have a scrollviewer which contains a childview. If anything in that childview has focus and I press down/up key, the content scrolls down/up.

This wouldn't be a problem if I didn't had just implemented a navigation system based on the arrow keys. So I use those 4 arrow keys the navigate between objects more easily. The problem now is that the content scrolls when the user presses up or down. I want to disable the scroll behavior.

I've already tried a few thing:

- Adding a KeyDown event to the scrollviewer, but it never gets hit.
- setting the istabstop to false on the scrollviewer
- setting the keyeventargs "handled" to true on the grid inside my scrollviewer, that gets called earlier then my code is executed (navigation), so can't use that either.

**Edit**

This is how the event are handled in XAML:

```
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <catel:KeyPressToCommand Command="{Binding CancelCellInputCommand}" Key="Escape" />
    <catel:KeyPressToCommand Command="{Binding LeftArrowNavigationCommand}" Key="Left"/>
    <catel:KeyPressToCommand Command="{Binding UpArrowNavigationCommand}" Key="Up"/>
    <catel:KeyPressToCommand Command="{Binding RightArrowNavigationCommand}" Key="Right"/>
    <catel:KeyPressToCommand Command="{Binding DownArrowNavigationCommand}" Key="Down"/>
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

Any other solutions I might try to prevent my content from scrolling on key up/down?

**Edit 2:**

After more researching, I see that the reason why bullet point 1 acts that way, is becasue the scrollviewer eats the keydown event, probably to make the scrolling happen. I haven't found a way to work around it yet though. Some guy says he sets his "IsTabStop" to false, but that makes no difference at all. Catching the KeyUp does work, but that's too late to prevent the key scrolling. My last resort is to not use the up/down keys for what I want, but going up and down in a cellgrid requires the up/down key, it's just logic.

I'd appreciate any help and thoughts on this, as I'm really stuck on this matter.

Comment: How did you implement your navigation system ? With Key bindings in the window ? By handling PreviewKeyDown ?

Comment: @VincentPiel: Updated the question, you can see how i get my events now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found something on the [Silverlight forums](http://forums.silverlight.net/post/272190.aspx).

After all, it resembles to Vincent Piels solution, it uses the PreviewKeyDown Event, but it needed a custom child (contentcontrol) for the event to be used in XAML.

Answer (score 2):

If you handle the keypressed tunneling event PreviewKeyDown, you can get the OriginalSource of the event, and then try and find its visual Ancestor which would be a ScrollViewer. If you cannot find a ScrollViewer ancestor, then handle your key as you already do. If you find one, then do nothing.

Comment: My third bullet point is what you suggest: I catch the event, and set e.Handled = true. The problem is that every time the custom needs to be executed, even if a visual parent is a scrollviewer. I just don't want it to scroll.

Comment: so you would need to catch it if it comes from a descendant of the scrollviewer (e.Handled = true in PreviewKeyDown ) then re-send the key from another control ...

Comment: Or i'm not sure if you shouldn't handle the keys in code behind. Less 'beautifull', but more simple solution leads to better code.

Comment: I don't have any problem using code-behind if it involves pure UI interaction anyway. One thing though, there are no preview actions on the scrollviewer in SL.